# How to capture datalayer object and print in my eclipse console using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, data-layers

I need to capture the datalayer from the console tab in the chrome developer tools

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please read [ask] and its linked resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will help you to get data layer information

```
   JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();

    ArrayList<Map<String, List<String> >> datalist = new ArrayList<>();

    //Execute google tag manage in the console using javascript executor to fetch values       
    datalist =  (ArrayList) executor.executeScript("return window.dataLayer");

    // Parse through GTM arrayList  
    for(int a=0; a < datalist .size(); a++) {
        for (String key : datalist .get(a).keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + "      " + datalist .get(a).get(key));

        }
    }
```

Comment: This pulls datalayer from the chrome console tab. How do i validate them?@Zakaria Shahed

Comment: You can validate this inside loop using assertion with your actual data.

Comment: Can you validate datalayer for this [link](https://www.adidas.co.in/), cause it will be a better understanding for me. Thanks in advance ! @Zakaria Shahed

Comment: Please share me your code, What you already tried so i can make a correction for you

Answer (score 0):

Im using the following code @Zakaria Shahed , pls make correction and how to use assertion here?

```
    List<String>actual_values=new ArrayList <String>();
    List<String>Notexist=new ArrayList <String>();
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    List<String> datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
    datalist =  (List<String>) executor.executeScript("return window.dataLayer");
    //System.out.println(datalist);
    String DLexpected_values=data[6];// i will read DLexpected values from excel sheet - data[6]
    List<String> splitword2 = Arrays.asList(DLexpected_values.split(","));
    
    for(String value :splitword2) {
        boolean b = false;
        for (String entry : datalist) {
            if(entry.toString().contains(value)) {
                actual_values.add(value);
                b = true;
                break; 
            }
            
        }
        if(!b) {
            if(!Notexist.contains(value)) {
                Notexist.add(value);
            }
        }
    }
    if(splitword2.equals(actual_values1)) {
        
        System.out.println("Expected_Values:"+" "+splitword2);
        System.out.println("Actual_Values  :"+" "+actual_values);
        System.out.println("Status         :      Pass");
        
    }
    else {
        
        System.out.println("Expected_Values:"+" "+splitword2);
        System.out.println("Actual_Values  :"+" "+actual_values);
        System.out.println("Missing_Values :"+" "+Notexist);
        System.err.println("Status         :      Fail");
        
    }
```